# how to write a regex to match my string

Tags: javascript, regex

How to write a JavaScript `RegExp` to match

```
'/api/users'
'/api/users/'
'/api/users?age=22'
'/api/users/?age=22'
```

but not

```
'/api/users/id'
```

**`Regex`** I have tried so far:

```
new RegExp('^' + '/api/users' + '\/?\\S*' + '$')
```

Comment: What have you got till now?

Comment: `id` specifically or anything that's not a `?...`

Comment: right, id is anything that's not a `?...`

Answer (score 0):

A pattern like this should work:

```
^/api/users/?(\?age=22)?$
```

Or assuming you want to match more than just a literal `22` for the age parameter:

```
^/api/users/?(\?age=\d+)?$
```

This will match a literal `/api/users`, followed by an optional `\`, followed by an optional `?age=` and one or more digits.

Of course when your constucting this as a regex literal, you need to escape the forward slashes:

```
^/\/api\/users\/?(\?age=\d+)?/$
```

Or escape the back-slashes and use the `RegExp` constructor:

```
new RegExp("^/api/users/?(\\?age=\\d+)?$")
```

Comment: You will need to escape the backslashes when using the RegExp constructor

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to match the querystring only if it starts with the age parameter:

```
/\api\/users\/?(\?age=\d+|$)/
```

`\api\/users\/?`will match /api/users or api/users/

`(\?age=\d+|$)`will match either ?age=22 or the end of string ($)

[Edit] Based on your comments, a simpler expression:

```
/\api\/users\/?(\?|$)/
```

`(\?|$)`will match either the start of a querystring (?) or the end of string ($)

Comment: Yes and no. I'm writing a regex to match a restful api, if the api url ends with '/' + any string but '?' is one case, else is another case.

Comment: I see. Then maybe this is closer to your need: /\api\/users\/?(\?|$)/ matches either a querystring (?) or the end of string ($)

Answer (score 0):

For match these string entirely and use as condition, you could use .test(subjectString):

```
(/^\/api\/users\/?(\?age=\d+)?$/).test(subjectString)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a negative look ahead for `/id` after `/api/users`:

```
/^\/api\/users(?!\/id).*$/
```

See a [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/Tz3rPifoIw) of this working with your examples.